# how to launch Net Beans 8.2 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8

I Cant Able to Launch NetBeans IDE in My ubuntu Suggest Me Any Idea To Run A NetBeans in My ubuntu System My ubuntu Version is 18.04

Answer (score 1):

first download netbeans8.2 for ubuntu version from the official site then download jdk8 from the official site.

1. Setting  jdk evironment

   set the jdk environment in ubuntu. as shown below [the commads are added in the .bashrc file in home directory( mostly the file is hidden u need to unhide by pressing ctrl+h on your keyboad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHuVN.png)

copy the following command and pest in .bashrc file

`# set path to JDK
export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/snap/jdk1.8.0_212
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

meaning you have to copy the jdk folder into snap folder for but it can be placed anywhere.

2. Installation of netbeans
   from the folder in which the netbeans is open the terminal and past the following commands

   `sudo chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh`
   `sudo ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh --javahome /home/guru/snap/jdk1.8.0_212`

you will be ok to install your netbeans using jdk8 with all libraries. 
enjoy your coding........

Answer (score 0):

If you had installed netbeans by downloading the **sh** installer from their website then try this code

```
./netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans
```

I hope it works for you

: D

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans has been updated and NetBeans 10.0 can now be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install netbeans
```

This is the most convenient way to install NetBeans because there are also several NetBeans support libraries in the default Ubuntu repositories. You can list these packages with the following command:

```
apt search netbeans
```